# How to set up a PDF network printer that will keep the PDF file

Tags: pdf, network-printers, virtual-printer

I would like to find a way to have a Windows computer share a virtual PDF printer with other local computers (that first part is easy!). However, I would like the PDF to be saved on the print server and not on the computer from which the print out is initiated. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is going to depend on your skill at resolving other driver problems.

I was able after several false starts to get a 32bit Win 7 peer user (admin) to print on My Win 10 restricted user Virtual printer. But the output result is not great so would need to dig deeper, than I need, just to find out why.
[image]

I used a GhostScript Virtual Printer since It allows remote users on network to download its drivers for ARM x64 and x32

It is hosted on a 64bit Win 10 restricted account so I had to jump through hoops to get it seen and accessible on the network, and then had to dig into it share settings to see 32bit/Arm clients need an extra check box on.

It took some challenges to get the 32bit client to see printer was available but it ran from there with the above test page output in the 64bit printme folder, Whilst monitoring that file visually real-time a print from the client was transmitted and instantly appeared on the host screen without noticeable corruption unlike the test print!!.

So an issue you could have is how to stop clients from overwriting the file whilst they are post processed (renamed like in a port redirection monitor) since my GS virtual printer uses a single named NoPromptPort.pdf

Your question should in effect be answered, However My Question is why go this route? It would be so much simpler efficient and reliable for each client to MSPrint to NoPromptPort.PDF then simply copy their renamed.PDF to a server folder.